# Foreach loop help c#

Tags: c#, .net, variables, loops, foreach

I'm currently trying to pull data from a database using a variable and then pass it into a foreach loop to determine if a button should be shown based on a value.

SO far I have this:

```
var Inter = from x in db.DT_Interviews where x.ClientID == int.Parse(ViewState["ClientID"].ToString()) && x.ClientID == CID select x;

foreach(var c in Inter)
{
    if (c.InterviewDone == true)
        BTI.Visible = false;
    else
        BTI.Visible = true;
 }
```

However I am unable to get the loop to work! Can someone show me or explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: maybe Inter is empty? what type of object is it?

Comment: Have you checked to see if `Inter` holds any elements?

Comment: unable as in it goes out of the loop in one iteration or skips the loop?

Comment: You say you can't get it to work - but what do you mean by that? What happens? You haven't given us enough information. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: It depends what exactly is going wrong... My guess is that currently BTI visiblity is being determined only by the last item in Inter. Do you want to exit your loop when you find one that is true or false or will there only ever be one value in Inter or what? You need to explain a bit more about what is going wrong and so on.

Comment: Put an extra `var items = Inter.ToArray();` and examine the contents  of `items` in the debugger.

Comment: look like you supress the status you just set --> imagine a client with 2 interviews, first done, second not done --> BTI is visible --> another client with 2 interviews, first not done, second done --> BTI is not visible. is that really the desired business logic?

Comment: Are you wanting to do something like displaying a list with a button on each row that is visible or not based on the InterviewDone value? or is there just one button on each page? Either way the code you have wont do this but it would be good to update your question with this info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, why have you got a foreach to set 2 scenarios only i.e. set the visibility of some object to false or true. Imagine if your Inter has got 5 bool values, then the visibility of your object is dependant upon the last value in the Inter because it will continue to loop until it hits the last value. Isn't it. Try this code:

Here, I am getting a bool value in Inter as soon as it finds the first value.

```
var Inter = (from x in db.DT_Interviews
             where x.ClientID == int.Parse(ViewState["ClientID"].ToString()) && x.ClientID == CID
             select x.InterviewDone).FirstOrDefault();

if(Inter)
{
    BTI.Visible = false;
}      
else
{
    BTI.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to show BTI if any interview is associated to the viewstate client ID and having the InterviewDone flag = true, you can use:

```
int clientID = int.Parse(ViewState["ClientID"].ToString());
BTI.Visible = db.DT_Interviews.Any(x => x.ClientID == clientID && x.InterviewDone);
```

But why do you need to check that the ClientID is same as the one in the view state AND CID?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very strange at several places:

```
var Inter = 
  from x in db.DT_Interviews 
  where x.ClientID == int.Parse(ViewState["ClientID"].ToString()) && x.ClientID == CID 
  select x;
```

Are you sure that your query returns any result? what is the value of CID?

```
  foreach(var c in Inter) 
  { 
     if (c.InterviewDone == true) 
            BTI.Visible = false; 
         else 
            BTI.Visible = true; 
      } 
  }
```

I am not sure that you are doing here? The BTI will be visible or not depeding upon the **last** element in your query. So, why to loop over the whole content then?